# Angular: Circular dependency (Abstract Service)

Tags: angular

I want to use an **abstract level** in my application to avoid direct communications between services (with business logic).

**THE CASE**

I build a UI module that will generate a list of records and a form for the selected record.
So User will be able to browse the list of records, add a new record and edit an existing record.

The form (new / edit) is going to be called from the list of records.

The concept is given below.

[image]

**THE PROBLEM**

To be able to call the abstract service and business services I need to implement them into each other. So I get a *"Circular dependency"* error.

**THE QUESTION**

- What is the best practice to organize and call services with the
  abstract layer?

**Architercure concept**

[image]

**The code sample**

*abstract.service.ts*

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AbstractService
{
    constructor
    (
        private Service1: Service1,
        private Service2: Service2,
        private Service3: Service3
    )
    
    callService1(): void
    {
        Service1.call();
    }
    
    callService2(): void
    {
        Service2.call();
    }

    callService3(): void
    {
        Service3.call();
    }
}
```

*Service1.service.ts*

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Service1 {
    constructor (
        private AbstractService: AbstractService
    )
    
    ngOnInit() {
        AbstractService.callService2();
        AbstractService.callService3();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're instantiating the service, it is not abstract anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that.

A circular dependency is always smelly even if it can be workarounded sometimes, it's better to avoid it.

In your case, the appropriate pattern would probably be to use "events" (observables) stored in the `AbstractService` and each other service can choose to push events and/or listen to them.

Although it's hard to give a definitive answer because it can be opinionated and you didn't give details about what the real use case is.

Comment: Thank you. I've added the case description. Any more detail suggestions?